# Identify a child of a <tr>

Tags: jquery

I have a table where each row contains 2 images. I need to perform an action on the row when either image is clicked. However, when I click on an image only the top row works. I know its because all the images have the same ID name that Im using in the click event but if I give them the unique ID's how do I write a onclick to catch them all?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("#UpClick").click(function()
    {
        alert("AS debug up");
    });
    jQuery("#DownClick").click(function()
    {
        alert("AS debug down");
    });
}); 


<form id="frm" action="AccountList.asp" method="post">
    <table id="sortList" class="pagetext">
        <tr glid="1008298">
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="DownClick"><img src="/images/report_desc2.gif"></a>
                <a href="#" id="UpClick"><img src="/images/report_asc2.gif"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkCopy" class="chkCopy" value="1008298">Test account (Accrual)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr glid="1008299">
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="DownClick"><img src="/images/report_desc2.gif"></a>
                <a href="#" id="UpClick"><img src="/images/report_asc2.gif"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkCopy" class="chkCopy" value="1008298">Test account (Vac)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr glid="1008300">
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="DownClick"><img src="/images/report_desc2.gif"></a>
                <a href="#" id="UpClick"><img src="/images/report_asc2.gif"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkCopy" class="chkCopy" value="1008298">Test account (PTO)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: use `class` instead of duplicated `id`, and use `.hasClass('class_name')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="DownClick">....
<a href="#" class="UpClick">....
```

**SCRIPT**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery(".UpClick").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("AS debug up");
    });
    jQuery(".DownClick").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("AS debug down");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you give the same ID to more than one element. That's illegal and jQuery can't find more than one element when you use `jQuery("#UpClick")`.

Use a class for that, so that you can bind using

```
jQuery(".UpClick").click(function() {
    console.log("AS debug up"); // yes, it's much easier to use the console than alert
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ID for the images assign them a class.

```
<a href="#" class="DownClick">
```

You can find elements according to their class with: `$(".DownClick")`